# java/swing: converting a text string to a Shape

Tags: java, swing, graphics, text

I want to convert some arbitrary text to a Shape ([`java.awt.Shape`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html)) and then stroke/fill the Shape to draw it. How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. Can you elaborate? Do you want the text to become the shapes of the characters in the text?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hm I did not know the answer to this but after a bit tweaking and poking around in with Eclipse content assist i found this which seems to be what you need:

**EDIT: i changed to code to change the way the string is displayed which is the reason you asked what you asked :) Try it. It renders the string with red color and a dashed outline**

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JPanel{

    private Shape s;

    public Test() {
        Font f = getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 70);
        GlyphVector v = f.createGlyphVector(getFontMetrics(f).getFontRenderContext(), "Hello");
        s = v.getOutline();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.translate(100, 150);
        g2.rotate(0.4);
        g2.setPaint(Color.red);
        g2.fill(s);
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 1, new float[]{1,0.4f,1.5f}, 0));
        g2.draw(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        Component c = new Test();
        f.getContentPane().add(c);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Also note that you can get the individual characters from the string by calling:

```
getGlyphOutline(glyphIndex)
```

Comment: Great -- I'm accepting this because it's a complete & understandable example. I'm puzzled because it looks like there are two ways to do this. The GlyphVector approach that you used, and the TextLayout approach that @objects answered with. Not sure what the advantages/disadvantages are of each.... in addition to a font and a text string, GlyphVector() seems to just take a FontRenderContext, but TextLayout takes a FontRenderContext and an AffineTransform.

Comment: indeed... It would be interesting to hear from a Sun employee (or from someone experienced in the matter) on the differences. It appears that TextLayout is used for many text glyph related operations such as caret shapes, switching characters... I initially thought that one of the two must be a new addition to the API but from what i can see both classes existed in the 1.4 API (for me and many that's the first version worthy enough to be called Java :P ).

Answer (score 5):

Use the [TextLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html) class (see the getOutline() method).
Theres an example [here](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-bookpage-34-3.html)

Comment: this example is a little more compact, much neater than the accepted answer too.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/OutlineFontpaint.htm

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this is not to address your exact answer, but it's a start...

```
//Rough pseudo code
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.TexturePaint;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;



BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();

//Paint with texturing brush
Rectangle2D rect2D = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
graphics.setPaint(new TexturePaint(image, rect2D));
graphics.fill(rect2D);

//Draw text
graphics.drawString("my text goes here", xPos, yPos);
```

In Summary,

1. Create a `BufferedImage` object of `width` and `height` and `ImageType`.
2. Get the image's `Graphics` object.
3. Paint that graphics like you please (i.e. create a rectangle, circle, text, etc.)
4. Write that image to a stream (file, ServletRequest, etc.)

Comment: Thanks but I want to stay in vector graphics

Comment: I suggest that you become more discreet with your question then @Jason S. We are trying to help, but we cannot read what's in your mind.

Comment: ?? I appreciate the help, but my question specifically asked how to convert text to a Shape, as in `java.awt.Shape`.

Comment: ok, I just saw the edited question now. It wasn't clear earlier. Look also @Holograham's comment below your question. Initially we were unclear about your question.