# Java - Convert character or string into a shape / area

Tags: java, string, graphics, shapes, graphics2d

I'd like to be able to convert any character or string into a shape or area, so that I can draw that character in whatever size, style, effects etc. I like.

To be more specific, I'm going to draw it using parallax so that it is only clearly defined at a certain angle (which is why I can't use html or anything of that nature). I already have the parallax set up, I just need the shape.

So in short, `public Shape convert(char c){...}`.

Alternatively if you can think of another way of achieving this, please let me know.

---

Just to give you a rough idea:

[image: writing in clouds]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466233/java-swing-converting-a-text-string-to-a-shape), it seems you can manage this as follows (assuming this method is defined on a subclass of `JPanel`):

```
public Shape convert(char c) {
    Font f = getFont();
    // Optionally change font characteristics here
    // f = f.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 70);

    FontRenderContext frc = getFontMetrics(f).getFontRenderContext();
    GlyphVector v = f.createGlyphVector(frc, new char[] { c });
    return v.getOutline();
}
```

It might be easier to declare the method to take a String argument, as you can pass a String as the second parameter to `createGlyphVector()` - plus this will likely be more efficient than converting each character individually if you need to do more than one.