# Create a Shape Object from Font Object in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, fonts, awt

I have a font object and a String. I want to return a Shape Object that is a representation of the String. I have a whole bunch of other classes that will display the String and take care of it.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this when I *do not* have a graphics/graphics2d object. Any Help? I have searched the net but had trouble finding helpful links.

```
public class SpecializationOfTester extends ParentTester {

    private String      str;
    private Font        font;


    public SpecializationOfTester(String str, Font font) {
        this.font = font;
        this.str = str;
    }

    public Shape getShape()
    {
        Shape           s;
        //
        //
        return s;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: You could always create a `Graphics2d` object.

Comment: Can I can use that Shape I end up with and add it to a different Graphics object later?

Comment: I guess it is so. At worst, a `Graphics2D` object will be held by the `Shape` and consume some memory.

Comment: Am I able to do that if this class extends a parent class? I changed my example

Comment: Every class extends some other class. If you don't extend explicitly, 'Object' is used.

Comment: Okay. I think I'm confused though. How do you create a Graphics2D object since its constructor protected?

Comment: See trashgod's answer. You can get one by creating a `BufferedImage` and getting the graphics object from that. Check out the answer he linked in the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`GlyphVector#getOutline()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/GlyphVector.html#getOutline%28%29), as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7466129/230513). You can create a graphics context in a `BufferedImage`, as discussed in [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).

See also these appealing examples:

- [`PictureText`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/230513), due to [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson).
- [`Test`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2466283/230513), due to [Savvas Dalkitsis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56242/savvas-dalkitsis).

Comment: [Also a relevant example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2466283/646634) that gets the `Shape` from a graphics object.

Comment: Hey I read it and it worked! I was able to do what I needed with the Shape I created and everything worked (strangely) perfectly!

Thanks for all the help people.